# What is causing my brake calipers to stick?

Tags: brakes, gmc, sierra

I sit at a job site with my 2009 GMC Sierra idling for heat, or aircon. After 20 minutes of idling, I go to drive off and the brake calipers are locked up. Already replaced pads, discs, short lines, booster, master cylinder, ABS. All that remains original is hard lines.
Truck has some rust on the underside. Wondering if the lines are cruddy and act like a check valve. Also wonder if the auto pedal adjust is malfunctioning while idling, filling the lines with pressure which can’t bleed off quickly. After shutting the truck off for 15-20 minutes, the brakes release and all seems fine. Scratching my head!! Is the pedal adjust controlled by one of the computers? Or, could the button be malfunctioning?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you know if your Sierra has hydroboost or vacuum assist brakes?

Comment: Paulster2, sorry I do not.

Comment: How can I ascertain that?

Comment: Could they have put the wrong type on when replacing?

Comment: Looked up work Midas did on truck 2/3/20. They claimed  the previous shop put Hydro boost pads and they replaced with Vacuum boost type.

Comment: Looking at the parts list for your vehicle, I can tell it most likely has a [hydroboost](https://www.rockauto.com/info/1091/B5034-RSID__ra_p.jpg). What I'm thinking is (without any proof) is the hydroboost is causing the issue. Not sure why after replacing it the problem would recur, but I'm VERY sure the lines are not the issue. All the lines do is pass the pressure. If the lines had a problem it would either be because it's crushed and not passing pressure or they burst ... no other way about it.

Comment: The pads are indifferent. The fact they put a vacuum boost on it would mean there's your issue. No clue why they would have done that, because it would be quite a bit of work to make it happen.

Comment: Midas note on their ticket says they thought the calipers stuck because having the wrong pads on it (hydro boost) causing everything to overheat because they weren’t retracting properly and overheating eventually made the calipers fail as well as ruining the disks. I guess Midas has a lifetime warranty on their work? Probably take it back to them. Meanwhile, this will be the third time repairing everything without finding a real cause.

Comment: What about sitting idling could cause the brakes to depress and seize? That has happened 3-4 times since Midas worked on it. Is it related to the pedal adjust system? Note, I am just sitting in the truck idling, no foot in the brake, no parking brake...then find the brakes are seized.